# Android IABv3 getSkuDetails for subscriptions don't return result

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I just upgraded from IABv2 to IABv3 (that actually supports subscriptions).

When I use getSkuDetails method for inapp products it works great, if I use it for subscriptions (with real IDs already published on market) it will return an empty array of subscriptions.

Someone knows if this is a bug or not?

I'm actually testing IABv3 with the Sample Application.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I just discovered that the problem is when in the list if productID requested you have duplicates.

To fix this you can change the querySkuDetails method: https://gist.github.com/StErMi/4987164